# When updating a whole project's root, how can I exclude svn externals from being updated?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

Is there a way to exclude all svn externals when doing a recursive update?

Is there a way to exclude only 1 of all of the svn externals when doing a recursive update?

Basically I'd like to cut down the svn update time, and a couple of the SVN externals that I have will just about never get updated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there is an option for this (to ignore all):

```
> svn update --ignore-externals
```

I don't know of any option to specifically ignore one or some externals while updating the rest.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using TortoiseSVN, you can do the same thing as "svn update --ignore-externals". Use the "**Update to revision...**" menu item instead of the normal "**Update**".
On that dialog you have a "**Omit Externals**" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend changing the default context menu items to have Update to Revision on the main context menu.

In the TortoiseSVN settings, go to 'Look and Feel', then uncheck items you want main folder context menu and check items you want in the submenu.

I have the following ***unchecked***.

- Checkout
- Commit
- Show Log
- Check for modifications
- Update to Revision

The great thing about having all these items is that they only show up when relevant, ie, when the directory is a working copy. So for a non SVN folder you will just get Checkout.

Comment: It probably took me longer than it should to understand why you **un**checked the most important items. Anyway, meanwhile you **_check_** the items you want on the main menu and **_uncheck_** the ones for the sub menu.